# Pattern for fscanf to retrieve number's information

Tags: c, text-files

I am trying to create an algorithm to read a file with this shape:

```
+6.590472E-01;+2.771043E+07;+
-5.003500E-02;-8.679890E-02;-
```

As you can see, it has three columns. Two of them are numbers, and the last one is a signal.

I've already have the line as a char[30] and the columns split by semicolon.

Now, let's assume the number "+6.590472E-01". I need to split it in four information: The sign (`+` or `-`), the number before the dot (0 to 9, in this case 6), the numbers between the dot and the exponent (590472) and finally the exponent (-01).

How can I use `fscanf` to retrieve those information? Which pattern do I have to use?

Comment: If you have the line in a string, you'll need to use `sscanf()`, not `fscanf()`.  What have you tried?  What format do you want the information in?  Strings, or a `char` for the sign and three integers for the other components?  Integers aren't good, in practice: `-31.00003E-29` gives problems if you lose the leading zeros on the `00003`, so presumably you need strings.

Comment: Jonathan, I need all the information in separated strings, as you told. Let's assume that I want to extract those information when I read the line with the fscanf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming declarations like:

```
 char s1[2], s2[2], s3[2];
 char int1[21], int2[21], frac1[21], frac2[21];
 char exp1[6], exp2[6];
```

and assuming that you read the line with [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) into a string variable `string`, then you can use `sscanf()` to parse the string in one swoop like this:

```
if (sscanf(string, "%1[-+]%20[0-9].%20[0-9]%*[eE]%5[-+0-9];%1[-+]%20[0-9].%20[0-9]%*[eE]%5[-+0-9];%1[-+]",
           s1, int1, frac1, exp1, s2, int2, frac2, exp2, s3) != 9)
    …something went wrong — at least we can analyze the string…
else
    …got the information…
```

Note the use of `20` in the format string but the use of `21` in the variable declarations; this off-by-one is a design decision made in the standard I/O library long ago (circa 1979), well before there was a standard.  The `%*[eE]` allows `e` or `E` as the exponent marker, and suppresses the assignment.  Note that the exponent term would allow `E9-8+7` as the exponent, and won't insist on a sign; there isn't a simple way around that unless you collect the exponent in two parts.

You also can't simply tell where the scan finished.  You could add a `%n` conversion specification at the end, and pass `&n` as an extra argument (with `int n;` as the variable definition).  The `%n` isn't counted, so the condition is unchanged.  You can then inspect `buffer[n]` to see where the conversion stopped — was it a newline, or end of string, or something bogus?

Note that because the format string uses `%[…]` scan sets throughout, no spaces are consumed — and any spaces in the input would trigger an error.

This requires a fairly comprehensive knowledge of the specification for [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html).  You'll probably need to read it half a dozen times in the next month or so to begin to get the hang of it, and then reread it another half a dozen times in the next year, and after that you may be able to get away with a yearly revision — it's a complex function (the `scanf()` family of functions are some of the most complex in standard C).

---

#### Test code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char string[] = "+6.590472E-01;+2.771043E+07;+\n";
    char s1[2], s2[2], s3[2];
    char int1[21], int2[21], frac1[21], frac2[21], exp1[6], exp2[6];
    int n;
    int rc;

    if ((rc = sscanf(string, "%1[-+]%20[0-9].%20[0-9]%*[eE]%5[-+0-9];%1[-+]%20[0-9].%20[0-9]%*[eE]%5[-+0-9];%1[-+]%n",
                s1, int1, frac1, exp1, s2, int2, frac2, exp2, s3, &n)) == 9)
    {
        printf("[%s][%s].[%s]E[%s]\n", s1, int1, frac1, exp1);
        printf("[%s][%s].[%s]E[%s]\n", s2, int2, frac2, exp2);
        printf("[%s] %d (%d = '%c')\n", s3, n, string[n], string[n]);
    }
    else
        printf("Oops (rc = %d)!\n", rc);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[+][6].[590472]E[-01]
[+][2].[771043]E[+07]
[+] 29 (10 = '
')
```

As noted by [chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187513/pattern-for-fscanf-to-retrieve-numbers-information/39187795?noredirect=1#comment65729446_39187795), a better way of writing the `if` statement might be more like:

```
    if ((rc = sscanf(string, "%1[-+]%20[0-9].%20[0-9]%*[eE]%5[-+0-9];"
                             "%1[-+]%20[0-9].%20[0-9]%*[eE]%5[-+0-9];" "%1[-+]%n",
                     s1, int1, frac1, exp1,
                     s2, int2, frac2, exp2, s3, &n)) == 9)
```

This uses adjacent string concatenation to emphasize that the first two segments of the format string are identical, and then splits the variables more or less to match.  There are many similar layouts that would also work.

Comment: You should protect the sign conversions with `%1[-+]` to avoid potential undefined behavior on crafted input.

Comment: @chqrlie: Oops: you're right — fixed, and Thank You.  It's `%c` only that assumes `1`, not `%[…]` too.  (You did know you could use `%20c` to read 20 characters, no null termination, didn't you.  Not that it's material to this question or my answer.)

Comment: Indeed, I had to implement `scanf` and all its quirks a couple times ;-)

Comment: It's a bit messy.  It's almost tempting to use a macro `#define FMT_BITS_OF_NUMBER "%1[-+]%20[0-9].%20[0-9]%*[eE]%5[-+0-9]"` and then `sscanf(FMT_BITS_OF_NUMBER ";" FMT_BITS_OF_NUMBER ";%1[-+]%n", …)` (or build the whole format as a single macro, or something) but ... there isn't a really clean way to do it.  … And 'quirks' is a polite way of describing some aspects of the `scanf()` family.  They're tricky blighters to use — I almost wish there was some simpler way to teach beginners because using `sscanf()` accurately is hard (as is implementing it accurately).

Comment: I would split the format string in 2 or 3 space separated parts, on 2 lines, and put the variables on 2 lines as well:
`sscanf(string,`
       `"%1[-+]%20[0-9].%20[0-9]%*[eE]%5[-+0-9];"`
       `"%1[-+]%20[0-9].%20[0-9]%*[eE]%5[-+0-9];"` `"%1[-+]",`
       `s1, int1, frac1, exp1,`
       `s2, int2, frac2, exp2, s3)`  Aligning the format fragments and similarly named variables to underscore the repetition.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that they have this format, you can simply use:

`int z = sscanf(var,"%g;%g;%c,&float1,&float2,&char1);`

where `char1` is a single `char`, and `float1` and `float2` are `float`s.
Verify `z == 3` to make sure you successfully got three variables filled.

Edit: I see you want the parts separated; then you could use:

`int z = sscanf(var,"%c%d.%[^E]E%3c;%c%d.%[^E]E%3c;%c",...)` with the proper number of variables. `%c` reads the first sign into a char, `%d` the integer number, the dot gets discarded, `%[^E]` reads *up to* the 'E', then the 'E' gets discarded, `%3c` reads the exponent, and so on.

Those formats work also in fscanf - fscanf internally maps to scanf anyway.